# Differentiability in $R^n$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

I have the definition of the derivative for $f:\mathbb R^n \rightarrow\mathbb  R^m$ at a point $a$ as:

$f$ is differentiable at a then there exists a linear map $L:\mathbb  R^n \rightarrow\mathbb  R^m$ such that

$\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)-L(h)}{||h||} \rightarrow 0$ as $h \rightarrow 0$ . (0, a, h are vectors in $\mathbb R^n$).

I am trying to derive from this definition that the following holds:

If we denote by $D(f(a))$ = total derivative of $f$ at point $a$ then it is true that if $f$ is differentiable at $a$:

$||f(x) - f(a) -D(f(a))(x-a)|| < \epsilon ||x-a||$ for $x$ close to $a$.

I know this seems (or it is) very easy but since the total derivatives is now a matrix of partial derviative I am not sure how to continue a proof. Extending it from $\mathbb R$ seems dangerous because I cannot say $D(f(a))(x-a) = L(x-a)$ or is this true?

Answer (score 1):

It appears as though you're missing a norm in your original definition.  The total (Frechet) derivative of a function $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is the linear operator $f^\prime(x)\in\mathscr{L}(X,Y)$ such that
$$
\lim_{\|h\|\rightarrow 0}\frac{\|f(x+h)-f(x)-f^\prime(x)h\|}{\|h\|}=0.
$$
Now, the definition of the limit means that for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists a $\delta>0$ such that
$$
\frac{\|f(x+h)-f(x)-f^\prime(x)h\|}{\|h\|}<\epsilon
$$
for every $\|h\|<\delta$.  Moving terms around, we have
$$
\|f(x+h)-f(x)-f^\prime(x)h\|<\epsilon \|h\|
$$
for every $\|h\|<\delta$.  Now, let $h=a-x$.  Then, we have
$$
\|f(a)-f(x)-f^\prime(x)(a-x)\|<\epsilon \|a-x\|
$$
for all $\|a-x\|<\delta$, which is what I think you want.

Comment: One usually defines $f(x)\to \ell$ by saying $\lVert f(x)-\ell\rVert \to 0$. The lack of the norm is not something to be worried about.

Comment: Following your proof, could I derive that $||f(a)-f(x)||<(\epsilon + ||f'(x)||)||x-a||$? I am confused what the norm of the m*n matrix $f'(a)$ is in this case. Thank you

Comment: Using the reverse triangle inequality, you can obtain $\|f(a)-f(x)\|-\|f^\prime(x)(a-x)\|\leq\|f(a)-f(x)-f^\prime(x)(a-x)\|<\epsilon\|a-x\|$, which then gives your inequality.  In this context, $\|f^\prime(x)\|$ denotes an [operator norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_norm).